# Angular 16 handle filter values in ag-grid-table with server side model type

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid table with server side model type and I would like to show all possible values for filter for each column if filter has type "`agSetColumnFilter`"

is there a way to show all possible values for a column a request to backend and get all possible values but without making an extra call ?

Otherwise I should get values for different columns

```js
<ag-grid-angular
  [rowModelType]="'serverSide'"
  [serverSideDatasource]="dataSource"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [autoSizeStrategy]="autoSizeStrategy"
  [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
  [headerHeight]="32"
  [sideBar]="sideBar"
  [rowSelection]="'single'"
  (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>

@Component({
  selector: 'my-grid-table',
  templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.scss']
})

export class GridTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() tableData: Data[] | undefined;
  @Output() gridReady = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() cellClicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

  private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

  gridApi: GridApi | undefined;
  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    pagination: true,
    suppressExcelExport: false,
    popupParent: document.body,
    onFilterChanged: this.onFilterChanged.bind(this)
  };
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'modelType',
      headerName: 'ModelType',
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        values: //filterValues,
        buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
        filterOptions: ['equals'],
        suppressAndOrCondition: true,
      },
    // ...
  ];

  constructor(
      private dataServerSideDataSource: DataServerSideDataSource
  ) {
  }
}
```